# Adding optional parameter

Tags: c#

I  want to give optional parameter value to objTest.TestNumber in my below code. My code as follows:-

```
 public class TestInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TestNumber { get; set; }
}       



public string TestUpdate(TestInfo objTest)
    {
        int retVal = 0;
        try
        {
            dataContext = new AccretiveAPIContext(GetConnection(locationId));
            retVal = dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                     "EXEC usp_TestUpdate @ID, @TestNumber",
                     new SqlParameter("@ID", objTest.Id),
                     new SqlParameter("@TestNumber", objTest.TestNumber),

                 );
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return retVal.ToString();
    }
```

Please tell the changes I need to make to make "@TestNumber", objTest.TestNumber as optional parameter. I want to set its default value to zero ("0").

Please help.

Comment: You would do this on the creation of the stored procedure. Or if you did want to do it here couldn't you just use a ternary statement?  new SqlParameter("@TestNumber", objTest.TestNumber == "" ? objTest.TestNumber : 0)

Comment: I want to make changes in code level not at procedure level

Comment: That isn't the way you should do this. Make it optional at procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or even easier -

```
            retVal = dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                 "EXEC usp_TestUpdate @ID, @TestNumber",
                 new SqlParameter("@ID", objTest.Id),
                 new SqlParameter("@TestNumber", string.IsNullOrEmpty(objTest.TestNumber) ? "0" : objTest.TestNumber),
```

Comment: my one parameter is integer, how can I use the above statement

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Your TestNumber property is a string and the Id is an integer.

Comment: if I change "string TestNumber { get; set; }" to "int TestNumber { get; set; }"

Comment: You could then make it a nullable int? and then the code would change to new SqlParameter("@TestNumber", objTest.TestNumber ?? 0)

Answer (score 4):

Change your TestInfo class as following:

```
public class TestInfo
{
    private string _testNumber;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TestNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_testNumber))
            {
                _testNumber = "0";
            }
            return _testNumber;
        }
        set { _testNumber = value; }
    }
}
```

You could also modify your method and say something like:

```
var testNumber = string.IsNullOrEmpty(objTest.TestNumber) ? "0" : obj.TestNumber;
```